# Cannot read property 'age' of null

Tags: javascript

So I made this simple js code and it gives me an error message "cannot read property 'age' of null. I don't understand why. anyone that can help me?

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(form){
if(form.age.value <=  "18"){
 alert("you can drink")
}
 else{
 alert("You can not drink")

 }
}
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your age" name="age" id="age">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check(this.form)"

</form>
</body>

<style>
head{
text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
  }
  body{
  text-align:center;
  background-color: brown;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed closing your input tag

Change this:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check(this.form)"
```

By this:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check(this.form)">
```

Comment: If that's the problem (it is) the question should be closed as a typo. Not gonna downvote your answer but please keep it in mind next time :)

Comment: Ok I didn't know :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't access the properties of the form this way.

Instead, getting the input element using in example [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Plus, I don't think people who are younger than 18 can drink :)

I changed the function call in the input by `onclick="check()"` (and you forgot to close the tag)

```js
function check(){
  let age = document.getElementById('age');
  if(age.value >=  "18") {
    alert("you can drink")
  }
  else {
    alert("You can not drink")
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your age" name="age" id="age">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check()">
</form>
```

Comment: God, I misread your entire answer, including the drinking age. I'll see myself out.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you was too young when started to drink :)

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that that error should be the result... but the problem is you're missing a closing `>` on the button's html. If you fix that it works:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(form){
if(form.age.value >  18){
 alert("you can drink")
}
 else{
 alert("You can not drink")

 }
}
  </script>


<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your age" name="age" id="age">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check(this.form)">

</form>

<style>
head{
text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
  }
  body{
  text-align:center;
  background-color: brown;
  }
</style>
```

Side note: reader-visible content should not go in the `<head>` of your page (not sure why the css is styling it) and you generally don't want to put anything after the closing body tag.

Comment: If that's the problem (it is) the question should be closed as a typo. Not gonna downvote your answer but please keep it in mind next time :)